# 2032 Flex error while contacting HTTPS REST services

Tags: actionscript-3, rest, apache-flex, ssl, https

I am new to using flex/actionscript code. I am making a GET/ HTTPS REST service call from my flex/actionscript code. 
Here is my code

```
  var service:HTTPService = new HTTPService();
        service.url = "https://wsexample/v2/";
        service.method = "GET";
        service.addEventListener("result", serviceResult);
        service.addEventListener("fault", serviceFault);
        service.send();
```

This is an HTTPS service call and I am getting the following error:

```
faultCode:Server.Error.Request faultString:'HTTP request error' 
faultDetail:'Error: [IOErrorEvent type="ioError" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2 text="Error #2032"].
 URL: https://wsexample/v2/'
```

When I open the HTTPS URL from my chrome browser, I get a NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID error and the following info:

```
This server could not prove that it is wsexample; its security certificate 
is not trusted by your computer's operating system. 
This may be caused by a misconfiguration or an attacker intercepting your connection.
```

And I click on this link ->Proceed to wsexample (unsafe). After I do this, the REST web service call seems to work fime from my flex application.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What does the certificate say?  Is it issued to wsexample?  Issued by a trusted authority?  Currently valid (i.e. not expired)?  This problem will certainly go away if you fix the certificate problem.

Answer (score 0):

How do you have flex services configured on your machine where the app is running? Make sure your flex compiler file has the proper settings. Aside from that, I would check to make sure the windows firewall settings have a rule set for your application. Lastly, make sure IIS is set to trust connections from your application. It really sounds like you have an security permissions issue that is generating the alert.